# On location change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, href

Is there a way to detect global location changes in AngularJS, not just single controller? My goal is to detect every location change.
Or is there any effective way to watch window.location.href for changes?

```
$routeChangeSuccess
```

As I understood is for single controller only or I'm wrong?

Comment: You could have a base controller that encompasses your entire app, and have that controller listen for the routeChangeSuccess event.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, `$routeChangeSuccess` is not limited to a single controller. It is broadcast from the `$rootScope` which means that it can be listened to on every scope (or, every scope that inherits from `$rootScope`) but is an application wide event.

There is also an undocumented event that works similar to `$routeChangeSuccess` called `$locationChangeSuccess`. The difference is that the former fires once a route has successfully changed and the latter fires when the URL is changed but before the route changes. Note that this isn't all URL changes, just times the URL changes in a way that the AngularJS application can register it (for example, a setter call to `$location.url()`).

Just to clarify, `$locationChangeSuccess` is broadcast from the `$rootScope` as well.

For both, you can listen to the event using `scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess')` or `scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess')`.

Answer (score 1):

For those using Angular-UI-Router, this event won't fire. "$stateChangeSuccess" is the right event for Angular-UI-Router. For more information on UI-router events, see this SO question:
[How to trigger UI-Router View Load events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607476/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-trigger-view-load-events)

and also the API guide:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events