# How to trigger UI-Router View Load events?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Testing ui-router for the fist time but testing the Events at the moment and I can't seem to understand how to trigger $viewContentLoaded or Loading. Although, I've got stageChangeSuccess, etc working! I just pushed everything to http://punkbit.com/space_competition/ but also added some code here. I expected to trigger the events when a new view is loaded to ui-view. But I guess I'm missing something here!

```
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1" ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- s: template partials -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="#/like_gate">like_gate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/terms_and_conditions">terms_and_conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/enter_competition">enter_competition</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <p>home.html template! fbLike is {{fbLike}}</p>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="enter_competition.html">
    <p>enter_competition.html template!</p>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="like_gate.html">
    <p>like.html template!</p>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="terms_and_conditions.html">
    <p>terms_and_conditions.html template!</p>
    </script>
    <!-- e: template partials -->
```

main.js

```
angular.module("space_competition", ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            resolve: {
                fb_like: 'fbLike'
            }
        })
        .state('enter_competition', {
            url: '/enter_competition',
            templateUrl: 'enter_competition.html',
            controller: 'enterCompetitionCtrl',
            resolve: {
                fb_like: 'fbLike'
            }
        })
        .state('like_gate', {
            url: '/like_gate',
            templateUrl: 'like_gate.html',
            controller: 'likeGateCtrl'
        })
        .state('terms_and_conditions', {
            url: '/terms_and_conditions',
            templateUrl: 'terms_and_conditions.html',
            controller: 'termsAndConditionsCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

        //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

})

.run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeStart', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                console.log("State Change: transition begins!");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                console.log("State Change: State change success!");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeError',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                console.log("State Change: Error!");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateNotFound',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                console.log("State Change: State not found!");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$viewContentLoading',
            function(event, viewConfig){ 
                console.log("View Load: the view is loaded, and DOM rendered!");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$viewcontentLoaded',
            function(event, viewConfig){ 
                console.log("View Load: the view is loaded, and DOM rendered!");
        });

})

.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, fbLike){

    $scope.fbLike = fbLike.liked();

})

.controller('enterCompetitionCtrl', function($scope, fbLike){

    fbLike.liked();

})

.controller('likeGateCtrl', function($scope){

})

.controller('termsAndConditionsCtrl', function($scope){

})

.factory('fbLike', function($http, $q){

    return {

        liked: function(){
            return true;
        }

    };

});
```

Anyone experienced could have a look please ?

Thanks : D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it looks like you have `$viewcontentLoaded` instead of `$viewContentLoaded`. did you forget to camel-case-capitalize the `C`?

Comment: thanks so much! I didn't noticed at all, it's working nicely for $viewContentLoaded, didn't noticed :)

Comment: this event is fired when the dom is added but before angular has finished processing the dom. You can test this by adding a id or class as angular variable and try to find it in $viewContentLoaded with jQuery. You will not find it.

Answer (score 1):

The $viewContentLoading event is now correctly firing with release 0.2.11: fix(state): [allow view content loading broadcast](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/7b78edeeb52a74abf4d3f00f79534033d5a08d1a)