# Angular page refresh on changing URL parameter in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

Extremely simple requirement but having a hard time with this. Have simple page where I print the parameter in the url path.

```
http://localhost:8888/ngtest.html#/1234567
```

**ngtest.html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{myId}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.myId = $location.$$path;
});
</script>
```

In the browser window:

1. change `1234567` to something like `1234`
2. hit Enter

Nothing happens. Hit F5 and it works as expected.

Not sure if this has something to do with browser behavior but how to force the page to refresh after parameter change + Enter?

Comment: You'll probably want to set up a routing function for that. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo&feature=youtu.be&t=58m11s

Comment: Why would you want to refresh anyway? The whole point of a SPA is to avoid that.

Comment: Definitely ok with not refreshing if it works. Basically i have inbound links like `http://example.com/view.html#/{item_number}`. Was trying to see if it will work without routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page refresh has been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

You can use `$route.reload();`

As suggested [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325406/on-location-change-in-angular) you can try listening for route change success when hitting Enter in the url input:

`scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess')` or `scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess').`

Comment: Figured out the registration added full code below. route reload is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Complete example based on Leon's suggestion above

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{myId}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

    // add a listener for when the url changes and user
    // Enter in the address bar
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
        $scope.myId = $location.$$path;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Basically location this is registering a location change listener and doing things accordingly. No routing config required